# Skfuzzy - get membership value from output

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, fuzzy, skfuzzy

I made a fuzzy logic model using skfuzzy.
On the basis of the calculated output, I would like to assign myself a category (low, medium, high) in the dataframe table to which the calculated value belongs.
I can't get the category name from the output.
How can I do it in skfuzzy?

My model:

```
def fuzzy_logic(s, v, d):
    h_max = pipe.max_h(d)
    i_min = pipe.min_slope(h_max, d)
    i_max = pipe.max_slope(d)
    slope = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(i_min, i_max + 1, 1), 'slope')
    v_min = 0
    v_max = 5
    velocity = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(v_min, v_max + 0.1, 0.1), 'velocity')
    diameter = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(1, 101, 1), 'diameter')

    # Populate slope with membership functions.
    slope['low'] = fuzz.trimf(slope.universe, [i_min, i_min, i_max / 2])
    slope['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(slope.universe, [i_min, i_max / 2, i_max + 1])
    slope['high'] = fuzz.trimf(slope.universe, [i_max / 2, i_max + 1, i_max + 1])

    # Populate velocity with membership functions.
    velocity['low'] = fuzz.trimf(velocity.universe, [v_min, v_min, 0.5 * v_max])
    velocity['medium'] = fuzz.trimf(velocity.universe, [v_min, 0.5 * v_max, v_max])
    velocity['high'] = fuzz.trimf(velocity.universe, [0.5 * v_max, v_max, v_max])

    # Populate diamter
    diameter['reduction'] = fuzz.trimf(diameter.universe, [1, 1, 50])
    diameter['optimal'] = fuzz.trimf(diameter.universe, [1, 50, 100])
    diameter['increase'] = fuzz.trimf(diameter.universe, [50, 100, 100])

    # Define rules
    r1 = ctrl.Rule(slope['low'] & velocity['low'] , diameter['reduction'])
    r2 = ctrl.Rule(slope['low'] & velocity['medium'], diameter['reduction'])
    r4 = ctrl.Rule(slope['medium'] & velocity['low'], diameter['reduction'])
    r8 = ctrl.Rule(slope['high'] & velocity['low'], diameter['reduction'])
    r9 = ctrl.Rule(slope['high'] & velocity['medium'], diameter['reduction'])

    r3 = ctrl.Rule(slope['medium'] & velocity['medium'], diameter['optimal'])

    r5 = ctrl.Rule(slope['low'] & velocity['high'], diameter['increase'])
    r6 = ctrl.Rule(slope['medium'] & velocity['high'], diameter['increase'])
    r7 = ctrl.Rule(slope['high'] & velocity['high'], diameter['increase'])

    diameter_ctrl = ctrl.ControlSystem([r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9])

    # compute
    diameters = ctrl.ControlSystemSimulation(diameter_ctrl)

    # calculate
    diameters.input['slope'] = s
    diameters.input['velocity'] = v

    diameters.compute()
    return diameters.output['diameter']

print(fuzzy_logic(s=20, v=1, d=0.2))
```

```
output: 32.23415721908444
```

This plot shows [efect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXNIW.png)

The value is in the low category.
How do you get it out of the model?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it. You can use `skfuzzy.interp_membership` and apply it to all the Consequent membership function and get the `max()` value:

```
print(interp_membership(diameter.universe, diameter['poor'].mf, diameters.output['diameter']))
print(interp_membership(diameter.universe, diameter['average'].mf, diameters.output['diameter']))
print(interp_membership(diameter.universe, diameter['good'].mf, diameters.output['diameter']))
```